# Represent Double as floating point binary string using built-in functions

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tostring, built-in

I'm using VB.NET, writing a winforms application where I'm trying to convert from a denary real number to a signed floating point binary number, as a string representation. For example, 9.125 would become "0100100100000100" (the first ten digits are the significand and the last six digits the exponent.).

I can write a function for this if I have to, but I'd rather not waste time if there's a built-in functionality available. I know there's some ToString overload or something that works on Integers, but I haven't been able to find anything that works on Doubles.

Comment: "signed floating point binary string" doesn't mean anything. "Binary" is the opposite of "String". If you meant string then use the [ToString() overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) that accepts a format specifier.  If you meant binary then use BitConverter.

Comment: Okay, my terminology isn't up to scratch. I mean a binary representation of a number, that can be stored in a string. Like "0110". ToString has an overload which can convert integers to an arbitrary base including binary, but not doubles. And I don't know if there is a format specifier to use binary - there doesn't appear to be one on MSDN.

Comment: I'm not aware of any format specifier that you could pass to ToString that would generate that format.

Comment: Very hard to see the point.  Only computers are ever patient enough to look at a string of 64 digits.  Humans will quickly ignore you.  But use BitConverter and write code to print the bits in each byte.

Comment: So negative, Hans. It's supposed to be a revision test. It chooses a real number at random and prints it as a 16-bit binary string (10 bit significand, 6 bit exponent), and then I have to work out the value in denary and enter it, then it checks for the correct answer.